# Why "The network connection was lost." Error occur in iOs?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, nsurlconnection

I am trying to access a url which is on https:// but i am accessing through http:// so why it is giving me the error of "The Network connection was lost" as my network connection is working fine.Is there any way to tackle it ?

Comment: Why don't you access it over http and not https if it's only available in https ?

Comment: My url can be dynamic it can be on http or https so i have to handle it and check for the protocol each time i access url.

Comment: You can not just use HTTP for HTTPS urls. HTTPS work on a different port and is secured, http is not. If the server allows you to connect on both protocols then it is possible, most server require you to use https for security reason and will not allow none https traffic.

Comment: you meet somethings about trust server problem, it's problem come from server. U can temporary fix it by trust any https server to continue connection. How to trust any server read more at http://www.indelible.org/ink/trusted-ssl-certificates/

Comment: But when i use https:// then it is working fine.In case of http:// it is showing the error.